# What kind of diagram best represents the field-level mapping from one system component to another?

Tags: data-structures, enterprise-architecture, modeling, data-modeling

In my environment, we have multiple systems developed independently by different teams.  Those teams frequently recreate the wheel because they're building applications, not building blocks.

As a trivial example, in one system, there may be a customer_no field, which may be an integer, but in a different system, that field may be called customerid, or simply customer.  It's clear to me that there is a correspondence between these fields, but not so much for junior developers and analysts.  In my scenarios, there are dozens of systems, each potentially holding on to hundreds of fields like this, so I'd like to be able to throw it into some modeling software and maintain it there instead of having to create one-off diagrams every time somebody wants to know all the systems that store a specific set of attributes.

And in my scenario, i'm not just limited to databases either.  Some teams will expose specific behaviors through webservices, and in that case, there's a strong desire to be able to map between fields in a request object to fields in a database.

As such, I find myself in need of a diagramming tool that would show two or more systems and allow me to connect the data models of the two systems.   I would like to be able to do this as field-level mapping.  Kinda like how you would map fields in a SSIS package, for those of you who have played around with that data transformation tool.  Imagine one entity on the left, One entity on the right, and lines connecting each of the fields that correspond to each other.

I'm wondering what modeling diagram (UML or Otherwise) would best represent this kind of mapping logic?   I'd prefer something that's standard across many modeling tools (sparx, altova, etc...) but am open to other options if such a tool doesn't exist in a standardized modeling framework.

Any recommendations?

Comment: "*Questions asking us to find or recommend tools, libraries, programming languages, resources (including books, blogs, tutorials, and examples), or projects to undertake are off-topic here*". It's an interesting question, but unfortunately it's not the sort of question we can answer here.

Comment: @DavidArno Which stack exchange site targets the knowledge domain of correlating modeling artifacts to the intended purpose?  I assume this one is apt  for this question, as it relates to the modeling of systems.   There are existing examples in this particular stack exchange where a user posted a specific UML diagram asking what kind of diagram it is.   This question asks the opposite question:  I have a problem domain that I want to model;  What diagram/model  is appropriate?  The reader doesn't need to be sensitive to a specific platform or tool to address the question.

Comment: honestly think a diagram is overkill - id just use a table